# Excel VBA Access

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, where .Fields... is not getting executed. Loop is directly closing the connection without adding records into table.

Code:

```
Sub insertIntoTable()

    Dim moviesConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim moviesData As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim moviesField As ADODB.Fields
    Dim r As Range

    Set moviesConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set moviesData = New ADODB.Recordset

    moviesConn.ConnectionString = conStrAccess
    moviesConn.Open

    On Error GoTo closeConnection

    With moviesData
        .ActiveConnection = moviesConn
        .Source = "tblFilmDetails"
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open

    On Error GoTo closeRecordset
        For Each r In Range("A3", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
            .AddNew
            .Fields("Title").Value = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Fields("Release_Date").Value = r.Offset(0, 2).Value
            .Fields("Length").Value = r.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .Fields("Genere").Value = r.Offset(0, 4).Value
            .Update
        Next r
    End With

    closeRecordset:
    moviesData.Close

    closeConnection:
    moviesConn.Close

End Sub
```

Please suggest

Comment: If you comment out the `On Error Goto` what happens?

Comment: It throws some error and close the record set and connection

Comment: Is the fields name correct? Also the data in excel should match with the data type defined in your database

Comment: What error does it throw?  _Some error_ could be anything from data type mismatch to out of memory because you've only got 16k installed (you're not on a Spectrum are you?).  First glance - shouldn't `.Fields("Genere").Value` be just `.Fields("Genere")`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get your code to work using this connection string:

> "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\best buy\Desktop\test.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

We can rule out data mismatch error because it throws a 3219 Runtime Error Operation before closing the connection.

[image]

`Range("A3", Range("A2").End(xlDown))` should probably be changed `Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup))` for two reasons:

1. It skips row 2
2. If there is no data beyond row 2 you will add 1048575 empty records (Ask me how I know)

If you have a large dataset you should comment out `.Update` and use `.UpdateBatch` after you have added all the records.  This will greatly improve performance.

```
    For Each r In Range("A3", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        .AddNew
        .Fields("Title").Value = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
        .Fields("Release_Date").Value = r.Offset(0, 2).Value
        .Fields("Length").Value = r.Offset(0, 3).Value
        .Fields("Genere").Value = r.Offset(0, 4).Value
        '.Update
    Next r
    .UpdateBatch
```

[image]
Note:  If you have the table open while adding the records then you have to press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the table and view the new data.

Comment: Good post. Quick question, how did you make the video?

Comment: Nice. I've seen it before but just didn't know how it was done. Thanks